# Rebind TAB to show help in counsel minibuffer

Tags: key-bindings, ivy, counsel

I'm in the process of migrating from helm to ivy/counsel, and I would like to replicate a binding that I had in my previous setup.

When browsing the results minibuffer (for example in `counsel-M-x`), I would like to have the help for the current result displayed when pressing `TAB`. To get help currently I need to do `M-o h`. Since this is an ivy action, I'm not sure how to add a key binding to just TAB.

Answer (score 3):

I've found the solution, `(intern (ivy-state-current ivy-last))` will return the symbol of the current ivy result, which I can then pass to `describe-function` or `describe-variable`.

```
(defun counsel-describe-function-or-variable ()
  "Display help about the currently selected ivy result.
Assumes the symbol is a function and tries with a variable describe-function fails."
  (interactive)
  (let ((inhibit-message t)
        (current-symbol (intern (ivy-state-current ivy-last))))
    (condition-case nil
        (describe-function current-symbol)
      ('error
       (describe-variable current-symbol)))))

(define-key counsel-describe-map (kbd "TAB") 'counsel-describe-function-or-variable)
```

I didn't find a way to properly distinguish between `counsel-describe-variable` and the rest of the describe commands, so I catch the error and try `describe-variable` when `describe-function` fails.

Answer (score 1):

I have adapted your answer and extend it to toggle *Help* window (helpful when we want it gone from the screen without leaving the minibuffer) and perform Ivy's native TAB (albeit with one more key stroke).

```
;;;###autoload
(defun my-ivy-toggle-help/tab (&rest _args)
  "Either describe current symbol or perform partial complete.
If last command is `self' and \"*Help*\" window is shown, delete it; else describe current symbol.
Ivy's native 2nd <TAB> is performed at the 3rd one."
  (interactive)
  (let ((help-window (get-buffer-window "*Help*"))
        (symbol (intern (ivy-state-current ivy-last))))
    (if (equal last-command 'my-ivy-toggle-help/tab)
     (if help-window
        (with-selected-window help-window
          (quit-window))
      (ivy-partial-or-done))
    (describe-symbol symbol))))
```